# how to use userDefualts to save printed array (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift3, save, nsuserdefaults, exit

How can I use userDefualts to save my array entries to make sure they re appear when user exits applications. I am trying to use userDefualts to save the var numbersWithCreationDate

```
  import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var entry: UILabel!
             var numbersWithCreationDates = [(Int,String)]()
       @IBOutlet var label: UITextField!

        @IBOutlet var scrolView: UIScrollView!


    @IBAction func enterScore(_ sender: Any) {

    if let text = label.text {
        if let number = Int(text){
               // let numberAndDate = (number,Date())

            let date = Date().description
            let numberAndDate = (number, date.substring(to: date.characters.index(of: "+")!))
                numbersWithCreationDates.insert(numberAndDate, at: 0)
                        //line in question
           entry.text = numbersWithCreationDates.map { "\($0.0)| \($0.1)" }.joined(separator:"\n\n")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(numbersWithCreationDates, forKey: "numbersWithCreationDates")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            }}

        else {
        entry.text = "Please Enter Number"

        }
```

//            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
//            defaults.set(numbersWithCreationDates, forKey: "SavedIntArray")

```
        }

                  }
extension Date {
    static var formattedNow: String {
        let now = Date()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "EST")
        return dateFormatter.string(from: now)
    }}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To set a standard default:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(numbersWithCreationDates, forKey: "numbersWithCreationDates")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

You may need to use class `NSNumber` instead of `Int` in your dictionary definition (but, maybe not, keys and vars need to comply with NSCopying to be saved as default)

To retrieve:

```
let numbersWithCreationDates = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "numbersWithCreationDates") as! [Int:String]
```

Comment: I edited my code with your suggestion. Sigarbt error is coming up.

Comment: 1. Don't needlessly call `synchronize`. 2. More importantly, you can't store an array of tuple in `UserDefaults`.